# rabbitMQ message forwarding from one queue to another

Tags: apache-camel, spring-rabbit

Could you please help me to resolve the problem I am facing?

When forwarding message from one queue to another ( no message seems to be published )  , 
steps:

1. timer publish current date to queue 'inbox'- this part working
2. from 'inbox' to 'outbox' - this is not working
3. from 'outbox' to print console

Follows the spring xml.

```
<route>
    <camel:from
        uri="rabbitmq://localhost:5672/outBox?sername=guest&amp;password=guest" />
    <camel:to uri="stream:out" />
</route>
<route>
    <camel:from
        uri="rabbitmq://localhost:5672/inbox?username=guest&amp;password=guest" />
    <camel:to
        uri="rabbitmq://localhost:5672/outBox?username=guest&amp;password=guest" />
</route>
<route>
    <camel:from uri="timer:foo?period=10" />

    <setBody>
        <simple>${body}Message at ${date:now:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}</simple>
    </setBody>

    <to
        uri="rabbitmq://localhost:5672/inbox?username=guest&amp;password=guest" />
</route>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to http://camel.apache.org/rabbitmq.html the URI format is

```
rabbitmq://hostname[:port]/exchangeName?[options]
```

Thus `inbox` in your code is not queue name but exchange.
Use `queue=` option to specify the queue